# Braintree stuck on "Credit card is invalid" page

Tags: ios, braintree

I just use Braintree for my payment gateway on my app.
I already test it few times using sandbox card `4111 1111 1111 1111` and it runs well. But when I try it with my real card, it show "Credit card is invalid"

I assume it because of the issuer country (Indonesia). But the main question is, I can't dismiss the error message and stuck up on this error dialog.

[image]

Comment: What version of the Braintree SDK are you using?

Comment: Also, where is that `UIAlertView` or `UIAlertController` coming from? I don't think the text "Credit card is invalid" appears anywhere in the Braintree SDK. See https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Credit+card+is+invalid

Comment: I pull github version on 12 Feb 2015, and integrate it manually.

Comment: The Alert view showed within the BrainTree controller right after I press the action button "pay now".
also from your links, there is a "Credit Card is Invalid" message on `BTDropInErrorStateSpec.m`.
Could the message come from braintree server after checking the CC number?

Comment: Please consider adding a breakpoint in `- [BTDropInErrorAlert show]` to examine the values of `self.retryBlock`, `localizedCancel`, and `localizedOK`.

Here: https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/3063ee110df37c6ca655d034a48dd6ce49fcabad/Braintree/Drop-In/BTDropInErrorAlert.m#L30

Comment: I think this is likely a manual integration issue. Please double the steps you took in your manual integration vs [the documented process](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/master/Docs/Manual%20Integration.md). Or, better yet, please follow the recommended integration instructions and use CocoaPods. See also [my comment on your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669385/briantree-drop-in-controller-not-show-correctly#comment45656882_28669385).

Comment: I already kind of solved this problem. I switch to pod install after they push update (3.6.1) and it fix the problem I encounter before (treat all warning as error and warn on missing eof).
And the cause of this un-dismissable dialog is because the OK button is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is related to my another problem on [BrainTree drop-in controller not show correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669385/braintree-drop-in-controller-not-show-correctly/28740288?noredirect=1#comment45788475_28740288)
. Somehow the manual installation makes most of text & label is missing, including the "OK" button on this problem.

I'm having trouble before when using pod install such as suddenly my project treat all warning as error, and warn/error from missing new line. It's all because somehow BT pod spec does push change on (`GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS` & `GCC_WARN_ABOUT_MISSING_NEWLINE`) to YES. And even I already change it back to NO, it still contain error `library not found for "lDeviceCollectorLibrary"`

And now after using pod install, I haven't found any problem. Here is the screen shoot after I use pod install.

[image]