# BrainTree drop-in controller not show correctly

Tags: ios, braintree

why my Braintree Drop-In controller doesn't have label for Credit Card, Expire date, and CVV on their respective TextField?

It only show blank textfield without label.

[image]

Comment: I guess you are using the downloaded library? I had the same problem and I used the pod instead which is also the recommended way

Comment: Yes, I using downloaded library. I already try pod, but somehow my project become error with strange error..  `No newline at end of file` on almost every file on my project .h and .m

Comment: New line shouldn't be there after @end tag.

Comment: exactly.. I'm not add space or anything. before I add BrainTree pod, everything is fine.. but after I add it and run `pod install`, that error shows up... If I turn `GCC_WARN_ABOUT_MISSING_NEWLINE` to NO, that error is gone, but somehow the inspector become super strict even unused variable shows up as error and stop the build.

Comment: Yeah it happens. Make sure you use all the variables if you're fiddling with the library files.

Comment: so it really does happened when adding BrainTree pod? the `newline` error and `strict` problem?
So I need to make adjustment when I adding BT pod?

Comment: I just found that BT pod change 2 flag, it change `GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS` and `GCC_WARN_ABOUT_MISSING_NEWLINE` to YES.. I already give the pod another shot and those flag into NO, but unfortunately there is still an error `library not found for "lDeviceCollectorLibrary"`

Comment: A recent update to the Braintree podspec introduced these `GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS` and `GCC_WARN_ABOUT_MISSING_NEWLINE` issues. Expect a fix shortly. We'll update here.

Comment: @TekYin in the meantime I've pushed [an (untagged) fix](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/commit/58792637ffe007488468264e116a9559adee7dea) for the `GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS` and `GCC_WARN_ABOUT_MISSING_NEWLINE` issues. Please try updating your Podfile to `pod 'Braintree', :head`. Once the build errors are fixed, let me know if the pod installation addresses the presentation issue.

Comment: @TekYin Braintree iOS 3.6.1 [fixes the issue build settings issue](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/commit/58792637ffe007488468264e116a9559adee7dea).

Comment: @TekYin I had the same problem. Any updates ? I also did manual install

Comment: @DaynaJuliana I haven't found the solution for manual install.. But new pod install resolve the issue without al of the error I mention before.. great assist Brent.. thank you very much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found the solution for manual installation. But new BrainTree Pod install (3.6.1) fix the problem (missing label) without showing another problem (`GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS` & `GCC_WARN_ABOUT_MISSING_NEWLINE`)

Comment: I know that was an issue with pods-they were treating all warnings as errors. I still had other issues with pods so choose to avoid that, clearly this is a bigger problem

Comment: @agf this may be something worth looking into

Comment: @DaynaJuliana actually all the problem I encounter before is from manual installation..  and the "treat all warning as error" is because they put the flag in the wrong place.